# Перевести код с Java AWT на JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, awt

Срочно нужно перевести код с `AWT` на `JavaFX`! Дело в том, что все хорошо, но:

а) происходят конфликты шрифтов `awt` и `javafx`;

б) не могу найти альтернативу `Graphics` для `JavaFX`;

в) Не знаю, как поместить это все в сцену.

Буду всем благодарен!

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;



class GameXonix extends JFrame {



    final String TITLE_OF_PROGRAM = "Xonix";

    final int POINT_SIZE = 10;

    final int FIELD_WIDTH = 640 / POINT_SIZE;

    final int FIELD_HEIGHT = 460 / POINT_SIZE;

    final int FIELD_DX = 6;

    final int FIELD_DY = 28 + 28;

    final int START_LOCATION = 200;

    final int LEFT = 37; // key codes

    final int UP = 38;

    final int RIGHT = 39;

    final int DOWN = 40;

    final int SHOW_DELAY = 60; // delay for animation

    final int COLOR_TEMP = 1; // for temporary filling

    final int COLOR_WATER = 0;

    final int COLOR_LAND = 0x00a8a8;

    final int COLOR_TRACK = 0x901290;

    final int PERCENT_OF_WATER_CAPTURE = 75;

    final String FORMAT_STRING = "Score: %d %20s %d %20s %2.0f%%";

    final Font font = new Font("", Font.BOLD, 21);

    Random random = new Random();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    JLabel board = new JLabel();

    Delay delay = new Delay();

    Field field = new Field();

    Xonix xonix = new Xonix();

    Balls balls = new Balls();

    Cube cube = new Cube();

    GameOver gameover = new GameOver();



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GameXonix().go();

    }



    GameXonix() {

        setTitle(TITLE_OF_PROGRAM);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setBounds(START_LOCATION, START_LOCATION, FIELD_WIDTH*POINT_SIZE + FIELD_DX, FIELD_HEIGHT*POINT_SIZE + FIELD_DY);

        setResizable(false);

        board.setFont(font);

        board.setOpaque(true);

        board.setBackground(Color.black);

        board.setForeground(Color.white);

        board.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, canvas);

        add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, board);

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                if (e.getKeyCode() >= LEFT && e.getKeyCode() <= DOWN)

                    xonix.setDirection(e.getKeyCode());

            }

        });

        setVisible(true);

    }



    void go() { // main loop of game

        while (!gameover.isGameOver()) {

            xonix.move();

            balls.move();

            cube.move();

            canvas.repaint();

            board.setText(String.format(FORMAT_STRING, field.getCountScore(), "Xn:", xonix.getCountLives(), "Full:", field.getCurrentPercent()));

            delay.wait(SHOW_DELAY);

            if (xonix.isSelfCrosed() || balls.isHitTrackOrXonix() || cube.isHitXonix()) {

                xonix.decreaseCountLives();

                if (xonix.getCountLives() > 0) {

                    xonix.init();

                    field.clearTrack();

                    delay.wait(SHOW_DELAY * 10);

                }

            }

            if (field.getCurrentPercent() >= PERCENT_OF_WATER_CAPTURE) {

                field.init();

                xonix.init();

                cube.init();

                balls.add();

                delay.wait(SHOW_DELAY * 10);

            }

        }

    }



    class Field {

        private final int WATER_AREA = (FIELD_WIDTH - 4)*(FIELD_HEIGHT - 4);

        private int[][] field = new int[FIELD_WIDTH][FIELD_HEIGHT];

        private float currentWaterArea;

        private int countScore = 0;



        Field() {

            init();

        }



        void init() {

            for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

                for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++)

                    field[x][y] = (x < 2 || x > FIELD_WIDTH - 3 || y < 2 || y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 3)? COLOR_LAND : COLOR_WATER;

            currentWaterArea = WATER_AREA;

        }



        int getColor(int x, int y) {

            if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > FIELD_WIDTH - 1 || y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 1) return COLOR_WATER;

            return field[x][y];

        }



        void setColor(int x, int y, int color) { field[x][y] = color; }



        int getCountScore() { return countScore; }

        float getCurrentPercent() { return 100f - currentWaterArea / WATER_AREA * 100; }



        void clearTrack() { // clear track of Xonix

            for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

                for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++)

                    if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TRACK) field[x][y] = COLOR_WATER;

        }



        void fillTemporary(int x, int y) {

            if (field[x][y] > COLOR_WATER) return;

            field[x][y] = COLOR_TEMP; // filling temporary color

            for (int dx = -1; dx < 2; dx++)

                for (int dy = -1; dy < 2; dy++) fillTemporary(x + dx, y + dy);

        }



        void tryToFill() {

            currentWaterArea = 0;

            for (Ball ball : balls.getBalls()) fillTemporary(ball.getX(), ball.getY());

            for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

                for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++) {

                    if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TRACK || field[x][y] == COLOR_WATER) {

                        field[x][y] = COLOR_LAND;

                        countScore += 10;

                    }

                    if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TEMP) {

                        field[x][y] = COLOR_WATER;

                        currentWaterArea++;

                    }

                }

        }



        void paint(Graphics g) {

            for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

                for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++) {

                    g.setColor(new Color(field[x][y]));

                    g.fillRect(x*POINT_SIZE, y*POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

                }

        }

    }



    class Xonix {

        private int x, y, direction, countLives = 3;

        private boolean isWater, isSelfCross;



        Xonix() {

            init();

        }



        void init() {

            y = 0;

            x = FIELD_WIDTH / 2;

            direction = 0;

            isWater = false;

        }



        int getX() { return x; }

        int getY() { return y; }

        int getCountLives() { return countLives; }



        void decreaseCountLives() { countLives--; }



        void setDirection(int direction) { this.direction = direction; }



        void move() {

            if (direction == LEFT) x--;

            if (direction == RIGHT) x++;

            if (direction == UP) y--;

            if (direction == DOWN) y++;

            if (x < 0) x = 0;

            if (y < 0) y = 0;

            if (y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 1) y = FIELD_HEIGHT - 1;

            if (x > FIELD_WIDTH - 1) x = FIELD_WIDTH - 1;

            isSelfCross = field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_TRACK;

            if (field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND && isWater) {

                direction = 0;

                isWater = false;

                field.tryToFill();

            }

            if (field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_WATER) {

                isWater = true;

                field.setColor(x, y, COLOR_TRACK);

            }

        }



        boolean isSelfCrosed() { return isSelfCross; }



        void paint(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor((field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND) ? new Color(COLOR_TRACK) : Color.white);

            g.fillRect(x*POINT_SIZE, y*POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

            g.setColor((field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND) ? Color.white : new Color(COLOR_TRACK));

            g.fillRect(x*POINT_SIZE + 3, y*POINT_SIZE + 3, POINT_SIZE - 6, POINT_SIZE - 6);

        }

    }



    class Balls {

        private ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();



        Balls() {

            add();

        }



        void add() { balls.add(new Ball()); }



        void move() { for (Ball ball : balls) ball.move(); }



        ArrayList<Ball> getBalls() { return balls; }



        boolean isHitTrackOrXonix() {

            for (Ball ball : balls) if (ball.isHitTrackOrXonix()) return true;

            return false;

        }



        void paint(Graphics g) { for (Ball ball : balls) ball.paint(g); }

    }



    class Ball {

        private int x, y, dx, dy;



        Ball() {

            do {

                x = random.nextInt(FIELD_WIDTH);

                y = random.nextInt(FIELD_HEIGHT);

            } while (field.getColor(x, y) > COLOR_WATER);

            dx = random.nextBoolean()? 1 : -1;

            dy = random.nextBoolean()? 1 : -1;

        }



        void updateDXandDY() {

            if (field.getColor(x + dx, y) == COLOR_LAND) dx = -dx;

            if (field.getColor(x, y + dy) == COLOR_LAND) dy = -dy;

        }



        void move() {

            updateDXandDY();

            x += dx;

            y += dy;

        }



        int getX() { return x; }

        int getY() { return y; }



        boolean isHitTrackOrXonix() {

            updateDXandDY();

            if (field.getColor(x + dx, y + dy) == COLOR_TRACK) return true;

            if (x + dx == xonix.getX() && y + dy == xonix.getY()) return true;

            return false;

        }



        void paint(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(Color.white);

            g.fillOval(x*POINT_SIZE, y*POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

            g.setColor(new Color(COLOR_LAND));

            g.fillOval(x*POINT_SIZE + 2, y*POINT_SIZE + 2, POINT_SIZE - 4, POINT_SIZE - 4);

        }

    }



    class Cube {

        private int x, y, dx, dy;



        Cube() {

            init();

        }



        void init() { x = dx = dy = 1; }



        void updateDXandDY() {

            if (field.getColor(x + dx, y) == COLOR_WATER) dx = -dx;

            if (field.getColor(x, y + dy) == COLOR_WATER) dy = -dy;

        }



        void move() {

            updateDXandDY();

            x += dx;

            y += dy;

        }



        boolean isHitXonix() {

            updateDXandDY();

            if (x + dx == xonix.getX() && y + dy == xonix.getY()) return true;

            return false;

        }



        void paint(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(new Color(COLOR_WATER));

            g.fillRect(x*POINT_SIZE, y*POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

            g.setColor(new Color(COLOR_LAND));

            g.fillRect(x*POINT_SIZE + 2, y*POINT_SIZE + 2, POINT_SIZE - 4, POINT_SIZE - 4);

        }

    }



    class Delay {

        void wait(int milliseconds) {

            try {

                Thread.sleep(milliseconds);

            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        }

    }



    class GameOver {

        private final String GAME_OVER_MSG = "GAME OVER";

        private boolean gameOver;



        boolean isGameOver() { return gameOver; }



        void paint(Graphics g) {

            if (xonix.getCountLives() == 0) {

                gameOver = true;

                g.setColor(Color.white);

                g.setFont(new Font("", Font.BOLD, 60));

                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

                g.drawString(GAME_OVER_MSG, (FIELD_WIDTH*POINT_SIZE + FIELD_DX - fm.stringWidth(GAME_OVER_MSG))/2, (FIELD_HEIGHT*POINT_SIZE)/2);

            }

        }

    }



    class Canvas extends JPanel { // my canvas for painting

        @Override

        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            super.paint(g);

            field.paint(g);

            xonix.paint(g);

            balls.paint(g);

            cube.paint(g);

            gameover.paint(g);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> а) происходят конфликты шрифтов awt и javafx;

Вам надо было сразу убрать

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
```

чтобы они не мешались в процессе.

> б) не могу найти альтернативу Graphics для JavaFX;

Это экземпляр `javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext`, получаемый из узла `Canvas` с помощью его метода `getGraphicsContext2D()`.

> в) Не знаю, как поместить это все в сцену.

Как-то так:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameXonix extends Application {

    final String TITLE_OF_PROGRAM = "Xonix (JavaFX)";

    final int POINT_SIZE = 10;

    final int FIELD_WIDTH = 640 / POINT_SIZE;

    final int FIELD_HEIGHT = 460 / POINT_SIZE;

    final int FIELD_DX = 6;

    final int FIELD_DY = 28 + 28;

    final int START_LOCATION = 200;

    final int LEFT = 37; // key codes

    final int UP = 38;

    final int RIGHT = 39;

    final int DOWN = 40;

    final Map<KeyCode, Integer> keyCode2int = new HashMap<KeyCode, Integer>() {{
        put(KeyCode.LEFT, LEFT);
        put(KeyCode.UP, UP);
        put(KeyCode.RIGHT, RIGHT);
        put(KeyCode.DOWN, DOWN);
    }};

    final int SHOW_DELAY = 60; // delay for animation

    final int COLOR_TEMP = 1; // for temporary filling

    final int COLOR_WATER = 0;

    final int COLOR_LAND = 0x00a8a8;

    final int COLOR_TRACK = 0x901290;

    final int PERCENT_OF_WATER_CAPTURE = 75;

    final String FORMAT_STRING = "Score: %d %20s %d %20s %2.0f%%";

    final Font font = Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 21);

    Random random = new Random();

    XonixCanvas canvas;

    Label board;

    Field field = new Field();

    Xonix xonix = new Xonix();

    Balls balls = new Balls();

    Cube cube = new Cube();

    GameOver gameover = new GameOver();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setTitle(TITLE_OF_PROGRAM);
        stage.setX(START_LOCATION);
        stage.setY(START_LOCATION);
        int fWidth = FIELD_WIDTH * POINT_SIZE + FIELD_DX;
        stage.setMinWidth(fWidth);
        stage.setMaxWidth(fWidth);
        int fHeight = FIELD_HEIGHT * POINT_SIZE + FIELD_DY;
        stage.setMinHeight(fHeight);
        stage.setMaxHeight(fHeight);
        stage.setResizable(false);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        board = new Label();

        board.setFont(font);
        board.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        board.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        board.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        board.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        board.setMinHeight(FIELD_DY / 2);

        canvas = new XonixCanvas(fWidth, fHeight - FIELD_DY);

        root.setTop(canvas);
        root.setBottom(board);

        stage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent e) -> {
            KeyCode code = e.getCode();
            if(keyCode2int.containsKey(code))
                xonix.setDirection(keyCode2int.get(code));
        });

        stage.show();

        go();

    }

    private Timeline timeline;
    private int skipKeyFrames = 0;

    void go() { // main loop of game

        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(SHOW_DELAY),
                (actionEvent) -> {
                    if (skipKeyFrames > 0) {
                        --skipKeyFrames;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (gameover.isGameOver()) {
                        timeline.stop();
                        return;
                    }

                    xonix.move();

                    balls.move();

                    cube.move();

                    canvas.paint();

                    board.setText(String.format(FORMAT_STRING, field.getCountScore(),
                            "Xn:", xonix.getCountLives(), "Full:", field.getCurrentPercent()));


                    if (xonix.isSelfCrosed() || balls.isHitTrackOrXonix() || cube.isHitXonix()) {

                        xonix.decreaseCountLives();

                        if (xonix.getCountLives() > 0) {

                            xonix.init();

                            field.clearTrack();

                            skipKeyFrames = 10;
                        }

                    }

                    if (field.getCurrentPercent() >= PERCENT_OF_WATER_CAPTURE) {

                        field.init();

                        xonix.init();

                        cube.init();

                        balls.add();

                        skipKeyFrames = 10;
                    }

                });

        timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        timeline.play();

    }


    class Field {

        private final int WATER_AREA = (FIELD_WIDTH - 4) * (FIELD_HEIGHT - 4);

        private int[][] field = new int[FIELD_WIDTH][FIELD_HEIGHT];

        private float currentWaterArea;

        private int countScore = 0;


        Field() {

            init();

        }


        void init() {

            for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

                for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++)

                    field[x][y] = (x < 2 || x > FIELD_WIDTH - 3 || y < 2 || y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 3) ? COLOR_LAND : COLOR_WATER;

            currentWaterArea = WATER_AREA;

        }


        int getColor(int x, int y) {

            if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > FIELD_WIDTH - 1 || y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 1) return COLOR_WATER;

            return field[x][y];

        }


        void setColor(int x, int y, int color) {
            field[x][y] = color;
        }


        int getCountScore() {
            return countScore;
        }

        float getCurrentPercent() {
            return 100f - currentWaterArea / WATER_AREA * 100;
        }


        void clearTrack() { // clear track of Xonix

            for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

                for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++)

                    if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TRACK) field[x][y] = COLOR_WATER;

        }


        void fillTemporary(int x, int y) {

            if (field[x][y] > COLOR_WATER) return;

            field[x][y] = COLOR_TEMP; // filling temporary color

            for (int dx = -1; dx < 2; dx++)

                for (int dy = -1; dy < 2; dy++) fillTemporary(x + dx, y + dy);

        }


        void tryToFill() {

            currentWaterArea = 0;

            for (Ball ball : balls.getBalls()) fillTemporary(ball.getX(), ball.getY());

            for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

                for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++) {

                    if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TRACK || field[x][y] == COLOR_WATER) {

                        field[x][y] = COLOR_LAND;

                        countScore += 10;

                    }

                    if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TEMP) {

                        field[x][y] = COLOR_WATER;

                        currentWaterArea++;

                    }

                }

        }


        void paint(GraphicsContext g) {

            for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

                for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++) {

                    g.setFill(Int2Color(field[x][y]));

                    g.fillRect(x * POINT_SIZE, y * POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

                }

        }

    }


    class Xonix {

        private int x, y, direction, countLives = 3;

        private boolean isWater, isSelfCross;


        Xonix() {

            init();

        }


        void init() {

            y = 0;

            x = FIELD_WIDTH / 2;

            direction = 0;

            isWater = false;

        }


        int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        int getCountLives() {
            return countLives;
        }


        void decreaseCountLives() {
            countLives--;
        }


        void setDirection(int direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }


        void move() {

            if (direction == LEFT) x--;

            if (direction == RIGHT) x++;

            if (direction == UP) y--;

            if (direction == DOWN) y++;

            if (x < 0) x = 0;

            if (y < 0) y = 0;

            if (y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 1) y = FIELD_HEIGHT - 1;

            if (x > FIELD_WIDTH - 1) x = FIELD_WIDTH - 1;

            isSelfCross = field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_TRACK;

            if (field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND && isWater) {

                direction = 0;

                isWater = false;

                field.tryToFill();

            }

            if (field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_WATER) {

                isWater = true;

                field.setColor(x, y, COLOR_TRACK);

            }

        }


        boolean isSelfCrosed() {
            return isSelfCross;
        }


        void paint(GraphicsContext g) {

            g.setFill((field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND) ? Int2Color(COLOR_TRACK) : Color.WHITE);

            g.fillRect(x * POINT_SIZE, y * POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

            g.setFill((field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND) ? Color.WHITE : Int2Color(COLOR_TRACK));

            g.fillRect(x * POINT_SIZE + 3, y * POINT_SIZE + 3, POINT_SIZE - 6, POINT_SIZE - 6);

        }

    }


    class Balls {

        private ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();


        Balls() {

            add();

        }


        void add() {
            balls.add(new Ball());
        }


        void move() {
            for (Ball ball : balls) ball.move();
        }


        ArrayList<Ball> getBalls() {
            return balls;
        }


        boolean isHitTrackOrXonix() {

            for (Ball ball : balls) if (ball.isHitTrackOrXonix()) return true;

            return false;

        }


        void paint(GraphicsContext g) {
            for (Ball ball : balls) ball.paint(g);
        }

    }


    class Ball {

        private int x, y, dx, dy;


        Ball() {

            do {

                x = random.nextInt(FIELD_WIDTH);

                y = random.nextInt(FIELD_HEIGHT);

            } while (field.getColor(x, y) > COLOR_WATER);

            dx = random.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1;

            dy = random.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1;

        }


        void updateDXandDY() {

            if (field.getColor(x + dx, y) == COLOR_LAND) dx = -dx;

            if (field.getColor(x, y + dy) == COLOR_LAND) dy = -dy;

        }


        void move() {

            updateDXandDY();

            x += dx;

            y += dy;

        }


        int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        int getY() {
            return y;
        }


        boolean isHitTrackOrXonix() {

            updateDXandDY();

            if (field.getColor(x + dx, y + dy) == COLOR_TRACK) return true;

            if (x + dx == xonix.getX() && y + dy == xonix.getY()) return true;

            return false;

        }


        void paint(GraphicsContext g) {

            g.setFill(Color.WHITE);

            g.fillOval(x * POINT_SIZE, y * POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

            g.setFill(Int2Color(COLOR_LAND));

            g.fillOval(x * POINT_SIZE + 2, y * POINT_SIZE + 2, POINT_SIZE - 4, POINT_SIZE - 4);

        }

    }


    class Cube {

        private int x, y, dx, dy;


        Cube() {

            init();

        }


        void init() {
            x = dx = dy = 1;
        }


        void updateDXandDY() {

            if (field.getColor(x + dx, y) == COLOR_WATER) dx = -dx;

            if (field.getColor(x, y + dy) == COLOR_WATER) dy = -dy;

        }


        void move() {

            updateDXandDY();

            x += dx;

            y += dy;

        }


        boolean isHitXonix() {

            updateDXandDY();

            if (x + dx == xonix.getX() && y + dy == xonix.getY()) return true;

            return false;

        }


        void paint(GraphicsContext g) {

            g.setFill(Int2Color(COLOR_WATER));

            g.fillRect(x * POINT_SIZE, y * POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

            g.setFill(Int2Color(COLOR_LAND));

            g.fillRect(x * POINT_SIZE + 2, y * POINT_SIZE + 2, POINT_SIZE - 4, POINT_SIZE - 4);

        }

    }

    class GameOver {

        private final String GAME_OVER_MSG = "GAME OVER";
        private final Font font = Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 60);

        private boolean gameOver;


        boolean isGameOver() {
            return gameOver;
        }


        void paint(GraphicsContext g) {

            if (xonix.getCountLives() == 0) {

                gameOver = true;

                g.setFill(Color.WHITE);

                g.setFont(font);

                g.fillText(GAME_OVER_MSG, (FIELD_WIDTH * POINT_SIZE + FIELD_DX - calculateMessageWidth()) / 2,
                        (FIELD_HEIGHT * POINT_SIZE) / 2);

            }
        }

        private int messageWidth = -1;

        private int calculateMessageWidth() {
            if (messageWidth < 0) {
                Text text = new Text(GAME_OVER_MSG);
                text.applyCss();
                text.setFont(font);
                messageWidth = (int) text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
            }
            return messageWidth;
        }
    }


    class XonixCanvas extends javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas { // my canvas for painting

        XonixCanvas(double width, double height) {
            super(width, height);
        }

        public void paint() {

            GraphicsContext g = this.getGraphicsContext2D();

            field.paint(g);

            xonix.paint(g);

            balls.paint(g);

            cube.paint(g);

            gameover.paint(g);

        }

    }

    private Map<Integer, Color> mapInt2Color = new HashMap<>();

    private Color Int2Color(int i) {
        if (mapInt2Color.containsKey(i))
            return mapInt2Color.get(i);
        java.awt.Color awtColor = new java.awt.Color(i);
        int r = awtColor.getRed();
        int g = awtColor.getGreen();
        int b = awtColor.getBlue();
        int a = awtColor.getAlpha();
        double opacity = a / 255.0;
        Color fxColor = javafx.scene.paint.Color.rgb(r, g, b, opacity);
        mapInt2Color.put(i, fxColor);
        return fxColor;
    }

}
```

Особенности:

- У меня JavaFX для шрифта по-умолчанию (System) не позволяет установить полужирное начертание. Поэтому в тексте программы используется "Arial". (Встречал в сети похожие сообщения. Возможно это из-за того, что у меня тут какая-то старая 32-битная версия Java 1.8.0_92 под WinXP).
- Исходный внутренний класс `Canvas` переименовал в `XonixCanvas` чтобы не путаться с `javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas`.
- Для преобразования int-цветов к типу `javafx.scene.paint.Color`, который используется в JavaFX, добавлена функция `Int2Color()` и кэш преобразованных значений `Map<Integer, Color> mapInt2Color`.
- Изображение и надписи немного отличаются, так как в JavaFX включен антиалиасинг.
- Игровой цикл построен на зацикленном `Timeline` с единственным `KeyFrame`. Использовать `AnimationTimer` здесь было бы не удобно,
  так как он срабатывает 60 раз в секунду, а периодичность обновлений в этой игре, заданная в `SHOW_DELAY`, равна 60 мс, что примерно соответствует 16.6 раз в секунду.
- Паузы после потери жизни реализованы пропуском 10 итераций игрового цикла (см. счетчик `skipKeyFrames`).
- Ширина надписи "GAME OVER" подсчитывается только один раз в `calculateMessageWidth()` и потом возвращает сохраненный результат.
- Чтобы для сравнения кодов клавиш не использовать устаревший метод `KeyCode.impl_getCode()`, используется карта `Map<KeyCode, Integer> keyCode2int`.
- Классу `GameXonix` установлен модификатор доступа `public` для того, чтобы метод `launch()` смог достучаться до `start()`.

---

**Дополнение (см. комментарии к ответу):**

Вариант метода `fillTemporary()` без использования рекурсии. Если этот метод использовать в исходном AWT-варианте игры, то можно раскомментировать две строчки (плюс установить `COLOR_TEMP` в другой цвет) и наглядно наблюдать, как это работает:

```
   void fillTemporary(int x, int y) {
        class FieldPoint {
            public final int x;
            public final int y;
            private FieldPoint(int x, int y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
        }
        ArrayList<FieldPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
        points.add(new FieldPoint(x, y));
        while (points.size() > 0) {
            int n = points.size();
            for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                FieldPoint p = points.get(i);
                boolean filledAround = true;
                for (int dx = -1; dx < 2; dx++) {
                    for (int dy = -1; dy < 2; dy++) {
                        if (field[p.x + dx][p.y + dy] == COLOR_WATER) {
                            field[p.x + dx][p.y + dy] = COLOR_TEMP;
                            points.add(new FieldPoint(p.x + dx, p.y + dy));
                            filledAround = false;
                            //System.out.println(points.size());
                            //canvas.repaint(); delay.wait(1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (filledAround) {
                    points.remove(p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не подскажете, как при изменении `FIELD_WIDTH` и `FIELD_HEIGHT` исправить глюк программы? А то после изменения, к примеру, на `1360` и `738` при отрезании ЛЮБОГО куска я почему-то перехожу на следующий уровень...

Comment: Это происходит из-за того, что для такого размера поля рекурсивные вызовы метода 
`fillTemporary()` требуют примерно 835 килобайт, что приводит к переполнению стека
32-битной JVM заданного по умолчанию размером в 320k 
(в 64-битной JVM стек по умолчанию выделяется большего размера 1024k и переполнение не происходит).

Для решения рекомендую переписать логику заполнения воды землей в методе `tryToFill()` так,
чтобы не использовать рекурсивные предварительные заливки с помощью `fillTemporary()`.

Обходной путь — это использовать параметр `-Xss1m` при запуске приложения.

Comment: Кстати, наглядно посмотреть, как работает алгоритм заполнения воды землей, можно в AWT-версии игры:
добавить `canvas.repaint(); delay.wait(1);` в методе `fillTemporary()` после строки `field[x][y] = COLOR_TEMP;`,
и изменить цвет временной заливки, например, на зеленый: `final int COLOR_TEMP = 0x00a800;`

Comment: Добавил в ответ вариант метода `fillTemporary()` без использования рекурсии.