# Помощь в переводе кода на java AWT в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, awt

Есть код на  java awt. Из него мне нужна была только "логика". Теперь же, мне нужно это "завести" чтобы оно работало через JavaFX. Исходный код написан на awt и все константы написаны под него. Большую часть я смог перевести, но не могу скомпилировать через fx. Остался последний вроде бы шаг. Очень нужно. Буду благодарен любой помощи. Вот код на AWT:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

class GameXonix extends JFrame {


final String TITLE_OF_PROGRAM = "Xonix";

final int POINT_SIZE = 10;

final int FIELD_WIDTH = 640 / POINT_SIZE;

final int FIELD_HEIGHT = 460 / POINT_SIZE;

final int FIELD_DX = 6;

final int FIELD_DY = 28 + 28;

final int START_LOCATION = 200;

final int LEFT = 37; // key codes

final int UP = 38;

final int RIGHT = 39;

final int DOWN = 40;

final int SHOW_DELAY = 60; // delay for animation

final int COLOR_TEMP = 1; // for temporary filling

final int COLOR_WATER = 0;

final int COLOR_LAND = 0x00a8a8;

final int COLOR_TRACK = 0x901290;

final int PERCENT_OF_WATER_CAPTURE = 75;

final String FORMAT_STRING = "Score: %d %20s %d %20s %2.0f%%";

final Font font = new Font("", Font.BOLD, 21);

Random random = new Random();

Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

JLabel board = new JLabel();

Delay delay = new Delay();

Field field = new Field();

Xonix xonix = new Xonix();

Balls balls = new Balls();

Cube cube = new Cube();

GameOver gameover = new GameOver();



public static void main(String[] args) {

    new GameXonix().go();

}



GameXonix() {

    setTitle(TITLE_OF_PROGRAM);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setBounds(START_LOCATION, START_LOCATION, FIELD_WIDTH*POINT_SIZE + FIELD_DX, FIELD_HEIGHT*POINT_SIZE + FIELD_DY);

    setResizable(false);

    board.setFont(font);

    board.setOpaque(true);

    board.setBackground(Color.black);

    board.setForeground(Color.white);

    board.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, canvas);

    add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, board);

    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            if (e.getKeyCode() >= LEFT && e.getKeyCode() <= DOWN)

                xonix.setDirection(e.getKeyCode());

        }

    });

    setVisible(true);

}



void go() { // main loop of game

    while (!gameover.isGameOver()) {

        xonix.move();

        balls.move();

        cube.move();

        canvas.repaint();

        board.setText(String.format(FORMAT_STRING, field.getCountScore(), "Xn:", xonix.getCountLives(), "Full:", field.getCurrentPercent()));

        delay.wait(SHOW_DELAY);

        if (xonix.isSelfCrosed() || balls.isHitTrackOrXonix() || cube.isHitXonix()) {

            xonix.decreaseCountLives();

            if (xonix.getCountLives() > 0) {

                xonix.init();

                field.clearTrack();

                delay.wait(SHOW_DELAY * 10);

            }

        }

        if (field.getCurrentPercent() >= PERCENT_OF_WATER_CAPTURE) {

            field.init();

            xonix.init();

            cube.init();

            balls.add();

            delay.wait(SHOW_DELAY * 10);

        }

    }

}



class Field {

    private final int WATER_AREA = (FIELD_WIDTH - 4)*(FIELD_HEIGHT - 4);

    private int[][] field = new int[FIELD_WIDTH][FIELD_HEIGHT];

    private float currentWaterArea;

    private int countScore = 0;



    Field() {

        init();

    }



    void init() {

        for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

            for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++)

                field[x][y] = (x < 2 || x > FIELD_WIDTH - 3 || y < 2 || y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 3)? COLOR_LAND : COLOR_WATER;

        currentWaterArea = WATER_AREA;

    }



    int getColor(int x, int y) {

        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > FIELD_WIDTH - 1 || y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 1) return COLOR_WATER;

        return field[x][y];

    }



    void setColor(int x, int y, int color) { field[x][y] = color; }



    int getCountScore() { return countScore; }

    float getCurrentPercent() { return 100f - currentWaterArea / WATER_AREA * 100; }



    void clearTrack() { // clear track of Xonix

        for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

            for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++)

                if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TRACK) field[x][y] = COLOR_WATER;

    }



    void fillTemporary(int x, int y) {

        if (field[x][y] > COLOR_WATER) return;

        field[x][y] = COLOR_TEMP; // filling temporary color

        for (int dx = -1; dx < 2; dx++)

            for (int dy = -1; dy < 2; dy++) fillTemporary(x + dx, y + dy);

    }



    void tryToFill() {

        currentWaterArea = 0;

        for (Ball ball : balls.getBalls()) fillTemporary(ball.getX(), ball.getY());

        for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

            for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++) {

                if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TRACK || field[x][y] == COLOR_WATER) {

                    field[x][y] = COLOR_LAND;

                    countScore += 10;

                }

                if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TEMP) {

                    field[x][y] = COLOR_WATER;

                    currentWaterArea++;

                }

            }

    }



    void paint(Graphics g) {

        for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)

            for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++) {

                g.setColor(new Color(field[x][y]));

                g.fillRect(x*POINT_SIZE, y*POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

            }

    }

}



class Xonix {

    private int x, y, direction, countLives = 3;

    private boolean isWater, isSelfCross;



    Xonix() {

        init();

    }



    void init() {

        y = 0;

        x = FIELD_WIDTH / 2;

        direction = 0;

        isWater = false;

    }



    int getX() { return x; }

    int getY() { return y; }

    int getCountLives() { return countLives; }



    void decreaseCountLives() { countLives--; }



    void setDirection(int direction) { this.direction = direction; }



    void move() {

        if (direction == LEFT) x--;

        if (direction == RIGHT) x++;

        if (direction == UP) y--;

        if (direction == DOWN) y++;

        if (x < 0) x = 0;

        if (y < 0) y = 0;

        if (y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 1) y = FIELD_HEIGHT - 1;

        if (x > FIELD_WIDTH - 1) x = FIELD_WIDTH - 1;

        isSelfCross = field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_TRACK;

        if (field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND && isWater) {

            direction = 0;

            isWater = false;

            field.tryToFill();

        }

        if (field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_WATER) {

            isWater = true;

            field.setColor(x, y, COLOR_TRACK);

        }

    }



    boolean isSelfCrosed() { return isSelfCross; }



    void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor((field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND) ? new Color(COLOR_TRACK) : Color.white);

        g.fillRect(x*POINT_SIZE, y*POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

        g.setColor((field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND) ? Color.white : new Color(COLOR_TRACK));

        g.fillRect(x*POINT_SIZE + 3, y*POINT_SIZE + 3, POINT_SIZE - 6, POINT_SIZE - 6);

    }

}



class Balls {

    private ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();



    Balls() {

        add();

    }



    void add() { balls.add(new Ball()); }



    void move() { for (Ball ball : balls) ball.move(); }



    ArrayList<Ball> getBalls() { return balls; }



    boolean isHitTrackOrXonix() {

        for (Ball ball : balls) if (ball.isHitTrackOrXonix()) return true;

        return false;

    }



    void paint(Graphics g) { for (Ball ball : balls) ball.paint(g); }

}



class Ball {

    private int x, y, dx, dy;



    Ball() {

        do {

            x = random.nextInt(FIELD_WIDTH);

            y = random.nextInt(FIELD_HEIGHT);

        } while (field.getColor(x, y) > COLOR_WATER);

        dx = random.nextBoolean()? 1 : -1;

        dy = random.nextBoolean()? 1 : -1;

    }



    void updateDXandDY() {

        if (field.getColor(x + dx, y) == COLOR_LAND) dx = -dx;

        if (field.getColor(x, y + dy) == COLOR_LAND) dy = -dy;

    }



    void move() {

        updateDXandDY();

        x += dx;

        y += dy;

    }



    int getX() { return x; }

    int getY() { return y; }



    boolean isHitTrackOrXonix() {

        updateDXandDY();

        if (field.getColor(x + dx, y + dy) == COLOR_TRACK) return true;

        if (x + dx == xonix.getX() && y + dy == xonix.getY()) return true;

        return false;

    }



    void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.white);

        g.fillOval(x*POINT_SIZE, y*POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

        g.setColor(new Color(COLOR_LAND));

        g.fillOval(x*POINT_SIZE + 2, y*POINT_SIZE + 2, POINT_SIZE - 4, POINT_SIZE - 4);

    }

}



class Cube {

    private int x, y, dx, dy;



    Cube() {

        init();

    }



    void init() { x = dx = dy = 1; }



    void updateDXandDY() {

        if (field.getColor(x + dx, y) == COLOR_WATER) dx = -dx;

        if (field.getColor(x, y + dy) == COLOR_WATER) dy = -dy;

    }



    void move() {

        updateDXandDY();

        x += dx;

        y += dy;

    }



    boolean isHitXonix() {

        updateDXandDY();

        if (x + dx == xonix.getX() && y + dy == xonix.getY()) return true;

        return false;

    }



    void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(new Color(COLOR_WATER));

        g.fillRect(x*POINT_SIZE, y*POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);

        g.setColor(new Color(COLOR_LAND));

        g.fillRect(x*POINT_SIZE + 2, y*POINT_SIZE + 2, POINT_SIZE - 4, POINT_SIZE - 4);

    }

}



class Delay {

    void wait(int milliseconds) {

        try {

            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);

        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    }

}



class GameOver {

    private final String GAME_OVER_MSG = "GAME OVER";

    private boolean gameOver;



    boolean isGameOver() { return gameOver; }



    void paint(Graphics g) {

        if (xonix.getCountLives() == 0) {

            gameOver = true;

            g.setColor(Color.white);

            g.setFont(new Font("", Font.BOLD, 60));

            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

            g.drawString(GAME_OVER_MSG, (FIELD_WIDTH*POINT_SIZE + FIELD_DX - fm.stringWidth(GAME_OVER_MSG))/2, (FIELD_HEIGHT*POINT_SIZE)/2);

        }

    }

}



class Canvas extends JPanel { // my canvas for painting

    @Override

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        field.paint(g);

        xonix.paint(g);

        balls.paint(g);

        cube.paint(g);

        gameover.paint(g);

    }

}
```

}

Переводить классы и методы XONIX, DELAY и остальные не нужно. Нужна помощь в переводе метода GameXonix и метода Go и метода Canvas.

Это пример моего кода, частично переведенного на FX.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    launch(args);
}


class Delay {
    void wait(int milliseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


class Field {

    private final int WATER_AREA = (FIELD_WIDTH - 4) * (FIELD_HEIGHT - 4);
    private int[][] field = new int[FIELD_WIDTH][FIELD_HEIGHT];
    private float currentWaterArea;
    private int countScore = 0;

    Field() {
        init();

    }

    void init() {

        for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++)
                field[x][y] = (x < 2 || x > FIELD_WIDTH - 3 || y < 2 || y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 3) ? COLOR_LAND : COLOR_WATER;
        currentWaterArea = WATER_AREA;

    }

    int getColor(int x, int y) {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > FIELD_WIDTH - 1 || y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 1) return COLOR_WATER;
        return field[x][y];
    }

    void setColor(int x, int y, int color) {
        field[x][y] = color;
    }

    int getCountScore() {
        return countScore;
    }

    float getCurrentPercent() {
        return 100f - currentWaterArea / WATER_AREA * 100;
    }

    void clearTrack() { // clear track of Xonix
        for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++)
                if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TRACK) field[x][y] = COLOR_WATER;
    }

    void fillTemporary(int x, int y) {
        if (field[x][y] > COLOR_WATER) return;
        field[x][y] = COLOR_TEMP; // filling temporary color
        for (int dx = -1; dx < 2; dx++)
            for (int dy = -1; dy < 2; dy++) fillTemporary(x + dx, y + dy);
    }

    void tryToFill() {
        currentWaterArea = 0;
        for (Ball ball : balls.getBalls()) fillTemporary(ball.getX(), ball.getY());
        for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++) {
                if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TRACK || field[x][y] == COLOR_WATER) {
                    field[x][y] = COLOR_LAND;
                    countScore += 10;
                }
                if (field[x][y] == COLOR_TEMP) {
                    field[x][y] = COLOR_WATER;
                    currentWaterArea++;
                }
            }
    }


    void paint (Rectangle g) {

        for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++) {
                g.setFill(Color.web(String.valueOf(field[x][y])));
                // g.fillRect(x*POINT_SIZE, y*POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE, POINT_SIZE);
                g.setX(x*POINT_SIZE);
                g.setY(y*POINT_SIZE);
                g.setWidth(POINT_SIZE);
                g.setHeight(POINT_SIZE);
            }
    }


}


class Xonix {

    private int x, y, direction, countLives = 3;
    private boolean isWater, isSelfCross;

    Xonix() {
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        y = 0;
        x = FIELD_WIDTH / 2;
        direction = 0;
        isWater = false;
    }

    int getX() { return x; }
    int getY() { return y; }
    int getCountLives() { return countLives; }

    void decreaseCountLives() { countLives--; }

    void setDirection(int direction) { this.direction = direction; }

    void move() {
        if (direction == LEFT) x--;
        if (direction == RIGHT) x++;
        if (direction == UP) y--;
        if (direction == DOWN) y++;
        if (x < 0) x = 0;
        if (y < 0) y = 0;
        if (y > FIELD_HEIGHT - 1) y = FIELD_HEIGHT - 1;
        if (x > FIELD_WIDTH - 1) x = FIELD_WIDTH - 1;
        isSelfCross = field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_TRACK;
        if (field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND && isWater) {
            direction = 0;
            isWater = false;
            field.tryToFill();
        }
        if (field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_WATER) {
            isWater = true;
            field.setColor(x, y, COLOR_TRACK);
        }
    }

    boolean isSelfCrosed() { return isSelfCross; }

    void paint( Rectangle g) {
        g.setFill((field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND) ?  Color.web(String.valueOf(COLOR_TRACK)) : Color.WHITE);
        g.setX(x*POINT_SIZE);
        g.setY(y*POINT_SIZE);
        g.setWidth(POINT_SIZE);
        g.setHeight(POINT_SIZE);
        g.setFill((field.getColor(x, y) == COLOR_LAND) ? Color.WHITE :  Color.web(String.valueOf(COLOR_TRACK)));
        g.setX(x*POINT_SIZE+3);
        g.setY(y*POINT_SIZE+3);
        g.setWidth(POINT_SIZE-6);
        g.setHeight(POINT_SIZE-6);

    }


}

class Balls {

    private ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

    Balls() {
        add();
    }

    void add() { balls.add(new Ball()); }

    void move() { for (Ball ball : balls) ball.move(); }

    ArrayList<Ball> getBalls() { return balls; }

    boolean isHitTrackOrXonix() {
        for (Ball ball : balls) if (ball.isHitTrackOrXonix()) return true;
        return false;
    }

    void paint(Circle g) {

        for (Ball ball : balls) ball.paint(g);
    }

}

class Ball {

    private int x, y, dx, dy;

    Ball() {
        do {
            x = random.nextInt(FIELD_WIDTH);
            y = random.nextInt(FIELD_HEIGHT);
        } while (field.getColor(x, y) > COLOR_WATER);
        dx = random.nextBoolean()? 1 : -1;
        dy = random.nextBoolean()? 1 : -1;
    }

    void updateDXandDY() {
        if (field.getColor(x + dx, y) == COLOR_LAND) dx = -dx;
        if (field.getColor(x, y + dy) == COLOR_LAND) dy = -dy;
    }

    void move() {
        updateDXandDY();
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    int getX() { return x; }
    int getY() { return y; }

    boolean isHitTrackOrXonix() {
        updateDXandDY();
        if (field.getColor(x + dx, y + dy) == COLOR_TRACK) return true;
        if (x + dx == xonix.getX() && y + dy == xonix.getY()) return true;
        return false;
    }

    void paint(Circle g) {
        g.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        g.setCenterX(x*POINT_SIZE);
        g.setCenterY(y*POINT_SIZE);
        g.prefWidth(POINT_SIZE);
        g.prefHeight(POINT_SIZE);
        g.setFill(Color.CYAN);
        // g.fillOval(x*POINT_SIZE + 2, y*POINT_SIZE + 2, POINT_SIZE - 4, POINT_SIZE - 4);
        g.setCenterX(x*POINT_SIZE+2);
        g.setCenterY(y*POINT_SIZE+2);
        g.prefWidth(POINT_SIZE-4);
        g.prefHeight(POINT_SIZE-4);
    }


}

class Cube {
    private int x, y, dx, dy;

    Cube() {
        init();
    }

    void init() { x = dx = dy = 1; }

    void updateDXandDY() {
        if (field.getColor(x + dx, y) == COLOR_WATER) dx = -dx;
        if (field.getColor(x, y + dy) == COLOR_WATER) dy = -dy;
    }

    void move() {
        updateDXandDY();
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    boolean isHitXonix() {
        updateDXandDY();
        if (x + dx == xonix.getX() && y + dy == xonix.getY()) return true;
        return false;
    }

    void paint(Rectangle g) {
        g.setFill(Color.web(String.valueOf(COLOR_WATER)));
        g.setX(x*POINT_SIZE);
        g.setY(y*POINT_SIZE);
        g.setWidth(POINT_SIZE);
        g.setHeight(POINT_SIZE);
        g.setFill(Color.web(String.valueOf(COLOR_LAND)));
        g.setX(x*POINT_SIZE+2);
        g.setY(y*POINT_SIZE+2);
        g.setWidth(POINT_SIZE-4);
        g.setHeight(POINT_SIZE-4);



    }


}

class GameOver {
    private final String GAME_OVER_MSG = "GAME OVER";
    private boolean gameOver;

    boolean isGameOver() { return gameOver; }


}
/*
void paint(Label g) {

    if (xonix.getCountLives() == 0) {
        gameOver = true;
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font("Uni Sans", 60));
        FontMetrics fm = g.
        g.drawString(GAME_OVER_MSG, (FIELD_WIDTH*POINT_SIZE + FIELD_DX - fm.stringWidth(GAME_OVER_MSG))/2, (FIELD_HEIGHT*POINT_SIZE)/2);

    }

}
*/

}
```

Comment: Перевод кода не входит в тематику Stack Overflow. Попробуйте разбираться с каждым классом и методом из AWT по отдельности. Если возникнут сложности при поиске аналога из Java FX, то задавайте конкретные точные вопросы.

Comment: Вообще, проблемы только с двумя методами. repaint и setbounds. Не знаете, как их можно заменить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перевести код с Java AWT на JavaFX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768896/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-java-awt-%d0%bd%d0%b0-javafx)