# Постепенная отрисовка java fx

Tags: javafx

Добрый день. Вопрос мой таков, как постепенно отрисовывать объекты на форме. 
Например если моя поставленная задача в том и заключается - в демонстрации постепенного построения графика (а не получении готового). Для этого я естественно кидаю main поток в sleep при каждом повторе цикла.

Пример в коде свел до максимальной простоты и краткости, чтобы можно было легко уловить суть проблемы.

Пробовал по разному.. Пытался создать отдельный поток из которого уже добавлял элементы в Pane, но в конечном счете ничего не вышло..

Вот короткий контроллер который сразу при инициализации рисует синусоиду с помощью MoveTo and LineTo:

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
public Pane idPane;


@FXML
private void initialize() throws InterruptedException {
    draw();
}

private void draw () throws InterruptedException {
    float step = 0.2f;
    float mash =20;
    for (float i = 0; i < 430/mash; i += step) {
        MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(i*mash, Math.sin(i)*mash + 50);
        LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(((i+step)*mash), Math.sin(i + step)*mash+50);
        Path path = new Path(moveTo, lineTo);
        idPane.getChildren().add(path);
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов — когда управление рисованием выполняется из другого потока, а само рисование выполняется в потоке "JavaFX Application Thread":

`// Controller.java:`

```
package iterate;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Pane idPane;
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    @FXML
    private Button buttonStart;
    @FXML
    private Button buttonStop;

    private Task<Void> task;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        startDraw(null);
    }

    private Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() {
                try {
                    draw();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    updateMessage(ex.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }

            private void draw() {
                float step = 0.2f;
                float mash = 20;
                Platform.runLater(() -> idPane.getChildren().clear());
                updateMessage("Рисование начато");
                for (float i = 0; i < 430 / mash; i += step) {
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        updateMessage("Рисование прервано");
                        return;
                    }
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        float i;

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(i * mash, Math.sin(i) * mash + 50);
                            LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(((i + step) * mash), Math.sin(i + step) * mash + 50);
                            Path path = new Path(moveTo, lineTo);
                            idPane.getChildren().add(path);
                            updateMessage("Отрисован шаг: i = " + i);
                            updateProgress(i, 430 / mash);
                        }

                        Runnable param(float i) {
                            this.i = i;
                            return this;
                        }
                    }.param(i));

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            updateMessage("Рисование прервано");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                updateMessage("Рисование завершено");
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateMessage(String message) {
                System.out.println(message);
                super.updateMessage(message);
            }
        };
    }

    public void startDraw(ActionEvent event) {
        if (task != null && task.isRunning()) {
            task.cancel();
        }

        task = createTask();
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        label.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

        buttonStart.disableProperty().bind(task.runningProperty());
        buttonStop.disableProperty().bind(task.runningProperty().not());
    }

    public void cancelDraw(ActionEvent event) {
        if (task != null)
            task.cancel();
    }
}
```

`// sample.fxml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="iterate.Controller">
    <center>
        <Pane fx:id="idPane"/>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <VBox>
            <Label fx:id="label"/>
            <ProgressBar fx:id="progressBar"/>
            <HBox>
                <Button fx:id="buttonStart" onAction="#startDraw" text="Поехали!" />
                <Button fx:id="buttonStop" disable="true" onAction="#cancelDraw" text="Стоп" />
            </HBox>
        </VBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

`// Main.java:`

```
package iterate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 430, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Преимущество такого подхода в том, что все вычисления можно проводить в фоновом потоке, а в потоке JavaFX — только вывод результатов. Это сохранит отзывчивость интерфейса при долгих вычислениях. Например:

```
        private void draw() {
            float step = 0.2f;
            float mash = 20;
            Platform.runLater(() -> idPane.getChildren().clear());
            updateMessage("Рисование начато");
            for (float i = 0; i < 430 / mash; i += step) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    updateMessage("Рисование прервано");
                    return;
                }

                // Расчеты, подготовка данных для вывода:
                MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(i * mash, Math.sin(i) * mash + 50);
                LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(((i + step) * mash), Math.sin(i + step) * mash + 50);

                updateMessage("Рисование: i = " + i);
                updateProgress(i, 430 / mash);

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    MoveTo moveTo;
                    LineTo lineTo;

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Вывод результатов:
                        Path path = new Path(moveTo, lineTo);
                        idPane.getChildren().add(path);
                    }

                    Runnable param(MoveTo moveTo, LineTo lineTo) {
                        this.moveTo = moveTo;
                        this.lineTo = lineTo;
                        return this;
                    }
                }.param(moveTo, lineTo));

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        updateMessage("Рисование прервано");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            updateMessage("Рисование завершено");
        }
```

Другой вариант — выполнять все в потоке JavaFX воспользовавшись одним из таймеров JavaFX: можно использовать `AnimationTimer` с пропуском ненужных итераций или `Timeline` с одним `KeyFrame`, в котором указать нужный интервал. Заметьте, что в этом случае вызывать `Thread.sleep()` не нужно.

Пример с `Timeline` можно посмотреть в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/810260/291565